# omit commas from echo output in bash

Tags: bash, csv, echo

Hi I am reading in a line from a .csv file and using

```
echo $line
```

to print the cell contents of that record to the screen, however the commas are also printed i.e.

```
1,2,3,a,b,c
```

where I actually want

```
1 2 3 a b c
```

checking the echo man page there isn't an option to omit commas, so does anyone have a nifty bash trick to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use bash replacement:

```
$ echo "${line//,/ }"
1 2 3 a b c
```

Note the importance of double slash:

```
$ echo "${line/,/ }"
1 2,3,a,b,c
```

That is, single one would just replace the first occurrence.

---

For completeness, check other ways to do it:

```
$ sed 's/,/ /g' <<< "$line"
1 2 3 a b c

$ tr ',' ' ' <<< "$line"
1 2 3 a b c

$ awk '{gsub(",", " ")}1' <<< "$line"
1 2 3 a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something more POSIX-compliant due to portability concerns, `echo "$line" | tr ',' ' '` works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the field values as separated values, can be useful to use the **IFS** built-in bash variable.
You can set it with "," value in order to specify the field separator for **read** command used to read from .csv file.

```
ORIG_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
do
        echo "Follow fields of record as separated variables"
        echo "f1: $f1"
        echo "f2: $f2"
        echo "f3: $f3"
        echo "f4: $f4"
        echo "f5: $f5"
        echo "f6: $f6"
done < test.csv
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

On this way you have one variable for each field of the line/record and you can use it as you prefer.


**NOTE:** to avoid unexpected behaviour, remember to set the original value to IFS variable